# setState in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Assume the following example:

```
const example = () => {
    const [objects, setObjects] = useState([])

    const asyncFunction = async() => {

         // This will trigger the API and assume it takes around 10 seconds to run
         let result = api.fetchObjects().then((result) => {
             // Here, setObjects will be called with the value it had at the moment the function started executing, not the actual value
             setObjects(result)
         }
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to do setObjects(result) and use the updated state? Let's say that the user can add objects to that state during those 10 seconds by different means in the app.

I have found a solution using useEffect, like this:

```
// Instead of setObjects(result)
const [updateObjects, setUpdateObjects] = useState(null)
setUpdateObjects(result)

useEffect(() => {
if (updateObjects !== null) {
setObjects(updateObjects)
setUpdateObjects(null)
}
```

Comment: What about `const result = await api.fetchObjects(); setObjects(result);` ?

Comment: That will run on every re-render. I need it to be in a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a functional state update to access and update from the previous state.

[functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState`
> does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState({});
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```

Using Promise-chain

```
const asyncFunction = () => {
  api.fetchObjects()
    .then((result) => {
      setObjects(objects => [
        ...objects, // <-- shallow copy previous state array
        result,     // <-- append new state
      ]);
    });
}
```

or using `async/await`

```
const asyncFunction = async () => {
  const result = await api.fetchObjects();
  setObjects(objects => [
    ...objects, // <-- shallow copy previous state array
    result,     // <-- append new state
  ]);
}
```

Depending on the *actual* state shape and `result` value your actual state update function may look a little different depending on your specific needs.

Comment: You are right with the spread operator but still 'objects' is the non-updated value. Assume that while the API runs, the user can add 10 objects to that lists. The setObjects will simply remove any entry added during the function execution time

Comment: @CristianNicolaePerjescu `objects` will be whatever the previous state value is at the time the state update is processed. It will be the latest state to update from, including all previous updates between `asyncFunction` being called and the Promise resolving. You are confusing the functional update with `setObjects({ ...objects, ...result })` which will possibly overwrite any previous state updates due to the way JS enclosures work.